# Обновление прав доступа PHPBB

Tags: phpbb

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при пользовании phpbb3(на второй работало), пишу из своего скрипта данные в таблиицу принадлежности пользователя к группе, все записывается нормально, в профилях пользователи числятся в группах, в админке тоже.. но права данных групп не распространяются на пользователей в них занесенных до изменения каких либо параметров принадлежности пользователя средствами самой цмс(установка группы по умолчанию для пользователя, запрос пользователя на вступление в любую группу.... т.е. любых действий с группами)..

Кто сталкивался?) у кого какие идеи будут)?

Comment: Да нет этот вопрос по адресу.

Answer (score 1):

Встроеные комманды движка

```
group_user_del($group_id, $user_id);
group_user_add($group_id, $user_id , false , false , false);
```